# How to Define a Schema for the Relationship of Events, Teams, and Members

Tags: graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

In Prisma, I'd like to model the following but I'm not really sure how.

```
type Event {
  id: ID! @unique
  players: [User]! @relation(name: "EventPlayers")
  teams: [Team]! @relation(name: "EventTeams")
  ...
}

type User {
  id: ID! @unique
  eventsPlayed: [Event]! @relation(name: "EventPlayers")
  ...
}

type Team {
  id: ID! @unique
  event: Event! @relation(name: "EventTeams")
  members: [User]! @relation(name: ?????)
  ...
}
```

### Constraints

1. Each `team member` must be in the `Event.players`
2. Each `Event.player` can only be assigned to one (or none) teams

### Question

I have a feeling I need a many-to-many relationship here, but I'm struggling to figure this out. What do I relate `Team.members` to ?????. Am I even approaching this correctly?

### More info (in case it's helpful)

I intend to create a drag-n-drop interface for creating teams. Those listed in `Events.players` but who have not yet been assigned as a `Team.member` will be in an `unassigned` bucket. Dragging them to a team, will assign them as a `Team.member`. But, I will want to query all players as `events { players { id }}` and `events { teams { members { id }}}`

### Update

After giving this more thought, I'm thinking about a different way to solve this problem. Here's an updated schema I'd love your thoughts/input on.

```
type Event {
  id: ID! @unique
  users: [EventUser!]!
  teams: [Team!]!
  title: string
}

type EventUser {
  event: Event!
  user: User!
  role: EventRole!
}

type User {
  id: ID! @unique
  events: [EventUser!]!
  name: string
}

type Team {
  event: Event!
  members: [EventUser!]!
  name: string
}

enum EventRole {
  ADMIN
  COORDINATOR
  JUDGE
  PLAYER
  REVIEWER
  SPONSOR
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of your model is accurate. There are a few minor changes you need to do:

1. Use of `@relation` directive: You need it only when a relationship is ambiguous. Example, **self-relationship**. You don't need it in your case. That is a traditional way of ORM thinking.
2. Nullability in relationships: Consider `players: [User]!` relationship. It says that players field cannot be null. It has to be **a list**. But it makes `User` as optional which means you can have `players = [user1, null, user2]`. You may not want this. This is applicable to almost all the **to-many** relationships.
3. `User` type should have a `team` field which is optional. There will be some users who will not be members of any team.

With the above adjustment, your schema will look like:

```
type Event {
    id: ID! @unique

    # Note DOUBLE EXCLAMATION
    # Ensure that User, as well as players, are not null.
    players: [User!]!

    # Note DOUBLE EXCLAMATION
    # Ensure that Team and teams are not null.
    teams: [Team!]!
}


type User {
    id: ID! @unique

    eventsPlayed: [Event!]!
    team: Team
}


type Team {
    id: ID! @unique

    event: Event!
    members: [User!]!

    # Added an extra key for keeping track of past events if required
    pastEvents: [Event!]!
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, and for explaining the double exclamation. I was thinking about that wrong for sure.  The problem is, each `Team` would only exist for a single event, so it wouldn't make sense to show past events as part of the team type. Users can belong to many teams. I've added a new schema. I'd love your thoughts.

Comment: @ChrisGeirman, It looks pretty good. Also, if you don't need `EventRole`, then you can get rid of `EventUser` model. And, you are missing ID for `Team`. Otherwise, it is perfect.

Comment: Thx! I've been playing with it and it's working out well so far.